# NodeJS: Download a file in headless chrome with Selenium

Tags: node.js, selenium

I am new to NodeJS. I am trying to download a file with Selenium in Headless chrome. It worked fine with non-headless mode. I saw some solutions with Python but I was not be able to apply it to NodeJS.

```
let downloadPath = path.resolve(`./public`);
const {Builder, By, Key, until, Capabilities} = require("selenium-webdriver");
const chrome = require("selenium-webdriver/chrome");
let options = new chrome.Options();
options
.addArguments("--headless");
.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
.setUserPreferences({
"browser.set_download_behavior":        "allow",
"download.default_directory":           downloadPath,
})
.setChromeBinaryPath(process.env.CHROME_BINARY_PATH)
let serviceBuilder = new chrome.ServiceBuilder(process.env.CHROME_DRIVER_PATH);

let scrape = async() => {
    let driver = await new Builder()
    .forBrowser("chrome")
    .setChromeOptions(options)
    .setChromeService(serviceBuilder)
    .build();

    await driver.get(url);
    await driver.findElement( By.css(download_selector) ).click();
}

(async() => {
    await scrape();
})();
```

Comment: What is `download_selector` in `driver.findElement( By.css(download_selector) ).click();` ? Can you share HTML ? Downloading should not be clicking on a button and verify if the file has been downloaded successfully in the desired folder ?

Comment: Oh, I think you don't need to pay attention to those. Everything worked fine in non-headless mode and the file was downloaded successfully to my disired folder. I think now the problem is about the setup of the driver?

Comment: No, It's not. The issue is here in the code

Comment: Sorry for my late response. Here's the entire code.
https://gitlab.com/QuangMan1109/selenium-test-2

Comment: Do you know how to setDownloadBehavior to allow :(( I think my syntax is incorrect